# Jasmine Gem - rake jasmine:ci doesn't run tests

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jasmine, phantomjs

So I have jasmine gem (https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-gem) installed in my project. And `rake jasmine` works perfect. It starts server and runs the tests, when I connect to the proper port. For Continuous Integration environment I want to use `rake jasmine:ci`, but it doesn't run any test and listens the port. Command call looks like this:

```
Puma 2.14.0 starting...
* Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
* Environment: development
* Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:57086
Waiting for jasmine server on 57086...
jasmine server started
```

How to make jasmine to run tests automaticly on jasmine:ci command? Thank you.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue suddenly :-( Did you able to get over this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem with jasmine gem and phantom 2.0.0+ as mentioned here: https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-gem/issues/244

Upgrading the jasmine gem to 2.5.2+ resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and found that the configuration file for `rake jasmine:ci` needed to be updated in order to reference the same files used by `rake jasmine`

Specifically I had to update `spec/javascripts/support.jasmine.yml` and set

```
src_files:
  - src/Whatever.js # Whatever your src is named
```

and

```
spec_dir: spec
```